# How to configure CGI on IIS 7?

Tags: iis, cgi, rebol

I did this

http://reboltutorial.com/images/rebol-iis.png

as explained here but it was for IIS 6
http://rebolforum.com/index.cgi?f=printtopic&topicnumber=39&archiveflag=new

I also activated 32 bits for application pool as explained here 
http://blogs.iis.net/wadeh/archive/2009/04/13/running-perl-on-iis-7.aspx

But when browsing to the test script it doesn't work, seems to take forever showing nothing, then in the end shows this message error:

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

I used a dedicated server on windows 2008

Source code of the test script:

```
REBOL [Title: "Cgi Test in Rebol"]
print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK^/Content-type:text/html^/^/";
print []
print ["Date/time is:" now]
print []
```

Should I ask on serverfault rather as nobody seems to know here ?

Comment: Did you enable CGI under "Application Development Features" in the "Torun Windows features on or off" dialog?

Comment: Yes that's the first thing I did.

Comment: I usually got problems using Rebol as CGI on IIS because of files & folders security settings and/or authentication settings on IIS.
I mean give IUSR_xxx read/execute access on necessary folders and rebol.exe. Try different Integrated Windows Authentication options.
I use it on IIS 5 but mostly I solved my problems trying these.

Comment: Hi thanks, will try. But IIS 7 is very different from IIS 5, won't you upgrade to IIS 7 any time in the future :)

Comment: I suggest you to first try with core.exe instead of rebol.exe (view.exe) because View shows an installation window when it start with a user account first time, which is IUSR_xxx in this case, and stays in the background for user action.

Comment: and also try this "c:\program files\rebol.exe" -csi "%s %s"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got my answer, here are the steps:

Open Server Manager from Administrative Tools. 
Add role "Web Server (IIS)" 
Try `http://localhost/` from your browser. You should see the IIS7 Welcome Page.

Copy core.exe to c:\ (or somewhere else), right click on core.exe and open Properties window, give Read & Execute access to IUSR_xxxx under Security tab. (If you've any problem, try to give Read & Execute for Everyone)

Open "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" from Administrator Tools.

Click on Default Web Sites, double click on Handler Mappings, click on Add Module Mapping from the right panel and type the followings:

```
Request Path: *.r 
Module: c:\core.exe -cs %s %s 
Name: Rebol
```

Select Yes when Add Script Map dialog box appears. It will add the c:\core.exe -cs "%s %s" as allowed under ISAPI and CGI Restrictions list.

Create a test.r file under wwwroot folder. My test.r file contains following script:

```
 R E B O L [Title: "Server Time"] 
 print "content-type: text/html^/" 
 print [<HTML><BODY>] 
 print ["Date/time is:" now] 
 print [</pre></BODY></HTML>]
```

And type `http://localhost/test.r` on your browser. 
If everything goes well then it should work.

If you are trying with View.exe then you may need to put --noinstall to command line, otherwise when View start with IUSR_xxx user account it will open desktop & installation window and it stays background (you can see it from Task Manager).

```
 c:\view.exe -csi %s %s
```

You may also need to put double quotes around %s if your script is in a path with spaces. Use the following form:

```
 c:\core.exe -cs "%s %s"
```

Instead of this:

```
 c:\core.exe "-cs %s %s" (<-- this won't work!)
```

I hope this will help.

UPDATE: I've faced a problem on IIS6 (Windows 2003 Server), it gives 404 when I configure it as follow (it works on IIS7 as told above):

```
c:\core.exe -cs "%s %s"
```

But it runs as:

```
c:\core.exe" -cs "%s" %s
```

Here is the link for Perl installation.
http://www.howtogeek.com/50500/how-to-install-perl-on-iis-6-for-windows-server-2003/

Comment: Try this also, change perl.exe to core.exe, http://sysadmingeek.com/articles/how-to-install-perl-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Oops it was such a long time I searched on Google and stumbled upon my own question and so your answer cause I really want to install rebol on IIS 7 now :)

Comment: Fantastic it works tested http://reboltutorial.com/cgi-bin/designpattern-quiz.cgi